# Does the human voice qualify as noise?

Tags: theory, voice

If we follow a common definition of noise, which is an aperiodic signal... Then is voice a noise? I've read lots of definitions on a certain free encyclopedia, but it could be that due to the nature of the site, I am mixing up terminology of different fields. Maybe it is neither, because it varies, since some consonants are periodic/more periodic than others(voiced), for example? But as what would you categorize it then?

Comment: Any plant that you don't want in your garden is a weed, no matter how beautiful it is. Same thing for sounds.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was going to comment the same thing. The reverse also holds: any sound/plant that you DO want is not noise/weed no matter how ugly.

Comment: I planted an intentional 'meadow' in my back garden - it still has weeds. My neighbours have a lovely lawn, but all summer I consider their voices whilst they're sitting on it to be nothing but bl**dy noise! One man's meat is another man's fish, as they say...

Comment: The human voice has four [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_register). And qualifies as a string and a wind instrument. https://soundbridge.io/human-voice-instruments/ .... And art is anything worth more than its scrap value.

Comment: > common definition of noise, which is an aperiodic signal... 

No, absolutely not.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Unless you're making [noise music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_music), e.g. by shaping / filtering white noise.  There can be rhythm to the changes, but usually still has energy distributed across a wide band of frequencies most of the time, and thus most clearly described as "noise".  In that case it's sound you do want, even though it's noise.  (But if you were making a recording of noise music, and people were talking in the background, or playing a piano, that would be "noise" in the sense of signal to noise ratio and desired vs. not.)

Comment: @DataProcessing +1 Actually I'm struggling to find *any* application where the definition would be useful.

Comment: @JiK Okay okay, I just cited this from Wikipedia.

Comment: The English language version of Wikipedia that I read says that "there is no distinction between noise and desired sound" and that the only difference is how a brain perceives it.  It doesn't mention aperiodicity at all.

Comment: @DataProcessing Yes, it's a different language.

Comment: Can't resist: "in some cases, yes." :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your "common definition" is not usefully applicable to real signals since there are no truly periodic real signals (they all start and end at some point of time).

Signals can have recognizably limited-time near-periodic components, and numerous such components are building blocks of speech phonemes.  Other building blocks are spectrally colored noise (fricatives and plosives, with plosives having phase-coherence that fricatives lack) which has a more spread-out spectrum compared to the near-line spectra of near-periodic components.

"Noise" typically is the opposite of "signal", meaning that it does not convey information.  That is not really a good categorisation for parts of speech.  The normal distinction here is to talk about "voiced" and "unvoiced".

With regard to musical instruments, one uses "pitched" and "unpitched" in related categories, and the categories are somewhat fluid as well: timpani generally count as pitched and drums as unpitched, but tuning/detuning can make them rather similar.

Comment: You paired up terms, and separated linguistics, acoustics, electronics, and music very nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds produced by the human voice are too varied to fit into a single category. Rather that "the human voice qualifies as noise", it would be best to say **"the human voice is capable of producing noise"**.

For example, singing "ah" on an open vowel, would not be noise by the definition offered. But clearing ones throat or growling would be noise.

Answer (score 6):

> "...mixing up terminology of different fields..."

I was thinking you might be. When you mention "consonants", "voiced", it sounds like linguistics. On a music forum "voice" *strongly* implies singing, and that is at least similarly periodic to other musical instruments that I think most would qualify as *not* noise.

> ...I've read lots of definitions on a certain free encyclopedia...

Don't be coy. If you link the page and point out the key parts of the text, it might help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The letter S is very noisy. So is letter T and K, and SH, CH. Consonants are often filtered noise. Vowels are harmonic. White TV noise is noise. Percussion is mostly noise, it spans many random frequencies. Ocean is mostly noise. Nearly all mammals produce mostly harmonic vocals. Voice is harmonic frequency formants with a little noise in it. Only sine tones are pure harmony. Only tv type noise is pure noise. Even seawaves and letter S have some tonal information.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise

Comment: I think white TV noise might be a thing from a bygone age :)

Comment: Synthesizers also have pink, red, and purple noise... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise

Comment: @DanPiponi - You can get the same thing by tuning a radio between stations.  The static can be used as a noise machine for sleep.

Answer (score 0):

> a common definition of noise, which is an aperiodic signal

The important word there is actually "a". This is "a" definition of noise.

> due to the nature of the site, I am mixing up terminology of different fields

You most certainly are.

From personal observation, English speakers hate making up words and would rather just repurpose old ones to have a new meaning and often this usage is *figurative* rather than literal. And of course you can do this multiple times to the same word. So a single word can actually can become multiple words that have the same spelling and pronunciation and are related by having a common ancestor, but aren't actually the same as the common ancestor and aren't the same as each other. (If they  have different spelling, they are called "[doublets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics))"...)

So you have a colloquial definition of "noise" (this is what you get if you ask a small child)--something that is loud, unpleasant, obscures whatever it is you're trying to hear, and so on. A loud, continuous hum from a fan would certainly be considered "noise".

And then you have new, specialized definitions of noise, each useful in their own context, but also could be considered as different words when compared to each other--for example, the "noise" in my photograph when the lighting is poor (not necessarily "loud", but random/with no meaning).

But you can't really treat them as the same word--any more than you can treat "guest" and "host" as the same word.

And to be complete, the definition you're using of noise is closer to the noise in my photograph, just an overly fancy way of saying "junk that is messing up the signal I was trying to send/receive".

Answer (score -1):

As posted in the Music stack exchange, by that definition, yes voice is noise, as is pretty much everything other than string instruments. Wind instruments being are a close approximation of "not noise" and percussion is solidly "noise" and voice is somewhere in between. In the musical context that definition is trying to separate out harmonic sources from non harmonic sources.

If the same question was posted on a the signal processing stack exchange I would say that it is not noise. In that field voice channels are historically the most common signal transmitted, so you could ask about the signal to noise ratio of radio broadcast as someone speaking and would not consider the voice as part of the noise.

For a signal to be perfectly periodic it has to continue for all time, and since that can't happen in reality, everything is aperiodic to some extent so the definition breaks down at long time periods in reality as well.

One place where that definition is particularly useful is when analyzing the sounds various shapes make when perturbed (plucked, struck, etc). When you analyze a circle (E.G. a drum head) you will see that you get aperiodic signals (specifically Bessel functions), while if you analyze a line (E.G. a violin string) you will get sin functions that are periodic. If you run the same analysis on a human vocal tract, you don't get periodic sin functions so it is noise. On the other hand it is not "as noisy" as a drum head.